# How do I count the rows in a table in the CodeIgniter framework?

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter

I'm trying to count the number of row in a table. The table has a fk 'city_id'. I want to count the number of the row that meets certain criteria and want to echo the number.

I've tried with the following code:

```
function count(){

  $citys = $this->db->get('city');

  foreach ($citys->result() as $city) {

    $this->db->where('info', array('city_city_id'=>$city->city_id) AND status_status_id==1);
    $sql = $this->db->count_all('info');

  }

  return  $sql->result;
}
```

Controller:

```
  $data['city'] = $this->state_model->count();
  $this->load->view('sview', $data);
```

View:

```
 <?php foreach($citys as $cities):?>
        <h4><?php echo $city ?>
      <?php endforeach;?></br></br>
```

In my model i'm trying to count the num of rows where lets say, city_city_id=1 and status_status_id=1 in my 'info' table.
 But i'm getting the following error :

```
   Severity: Notice

 Message: Use of undefined constant status_status_id - assumed 'status_status_id'

 Filename: models/State_model.php

 Line Number: 98
```

In line 98 i have

```
         $this->db->where('info', array('city_city_id'=>$city->city_id) AND                    status_status_id==1);
```

i'm newly working with codeigniter so a little help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

This should get you going:

```
$this->db->where('city_id', $city_id);
$this->db->from('city');
return $this->db->count_all_results();
```

Returns an integer. [CodeIgniter Active Record](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html)

You can’t use SQL queries in the middle of PHP, that’s why `AND` breaks it. You don’t need to join the queries with `AND`, CodeIgniter does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

your where should go like

```
    $this->db->where('info', array('city_city_id'=>$city->city_id, 
'status_status_id'=>'1'));
```